# VB.Net Merge property class from more than one web references

Tags: vb.net, web-services, reference

I have project that need to reference to some web service, just say my reference is 

**service1Facade** and **service2Facade**
both of them contain class name **objectA** 
i must load objectA from service1Facade and use it as parameter in service2Facade.
but i got error 
*"value of type service1Facade.objectA cannot be converted to service2Facade.objectA"*

how can i convert these object ?

what i have try but still not work:

1. group all reference into same folder, but .NET change its name into
   **objectA** and **objectA1**
2. I copy every property of the property inside **objectA**, but still not working.

Comment: Is the `objectA` class defined in a common library that is referenced by all three projects?

Comment: If the class is defined in a common library that is referenced by all three projects, when you add the **Service Reference**, you can go to the **Advanced...** options and select the **Reuse types in referenced assemblies** option.

Comment: @StevenDoggart thank you for your suggestion, i have already select reuses type, but i dont see my class listed inside its list, also i got the service working online with web reference (**i don't know why, but service reference just not work fo me**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality that is responsible for generating proxy classes based on your WSDL specification doesn't know (and *it shouldn't know*) that both your services use the same underlying type for `objectA`, and as I mentioned, no assumptions can be made regarding this since web services are meant to be decoupled from each other (from the consumer point of view).

I'd say your best option is to have your own proxy class (let's say `ServiceProxyDTO`) that can be used in both service #1 and #2. Something along the lines of:

```
public class ServiceProxyDTO
{
  // Define properties from "objectA"

  public ServiceProxyDTO() { }

  public ServiceProxyDTO(service1Facade.ObjectA copyFrom)
  {
    // Copy state from "copyFrom"
  }

  public ServiceProxyDTO(service2Facade.ObjectA copyFrom)
  {
    // Copy state from "copyFrom"
  }

  public static implicit operator service1Facade.ObjectA(ServiceProxyDTO dto)
  {
    return new service1Facade.ObjectA() { /* Copy state back */ };
  }

  public static implicit operator service2Facade.ObjectA(ServiceProxyDTO dto)
  {
    return new service2Facade.ObjectA() { /* Copy state back */ };
  }

  public static implicit operator ServiceProxyDTO(service1Facade.ObjectA obj)
  {
    return new ServiceProxyDTO(obj);
  }

  public static implicit operator ServiceProxyDTO(service2Facade.ObjectA obj)
  {
    return new ServiceProxyDTO(obj);
  }
}
```

With this code you can instantiate `ServiceProxyDTO` and pass it as parameter to both service #1 and #2 (as well as get the return values from both of these services).

Hope this helps.

Comment: i try your solution, and yes, the service want to accept my parameter, but do you have another option, because most of property inside my class also a class that have same problem.

Comment: @user3073660 you can use T4 templates for generating the complete object graph automatically. I'm sorry but this is the only solution I can recommend and which I tired myself.

Comment: You could edit the proxy classes manually and change them to both use the same actual class.  Or manually gut out the two proxy DTO's and make them both inherit the from one DTO class.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Good point, but in this case you're risking to loose all your changes whenever you update service reference.

Comment: @volpav, Correct, I should have mentioned that as the downside :)

Comment: @volpav thanks a lot, after i've create all DTO, everything works as expected. ^^